# Python pandas groupby sum displaying wrong output

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using groupby sum and I am getting the wrong output:

[image: This is my dataframe]

Although the medal column only contains value of either `0` or `1`, I am getting this output after executing the following code.

```
test=oly_new.groupby(['Country','Year'])['Medal'].sum()
```

[image]

Comment: please read [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Medal` column is a `str`, convert first to `int` and then sum:

```
oly_new['Medal'] = oly_new['Medal'].astype(int)
test=oly_new.groupby(['Country','Year'])['Medal'].sum()
```

When your column `dtype` is `str` then the `sum` function just concatenates all the strings

Comment: Also, for future reference, posting images is frowned upon. You should post raw data, code to recreate your df, the desired output, and your existing code. Also remember to accept my answer, there will be an empty tick under the down arrow at the top left of my answer